# Why can I not create a new home page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1

I am on Magento 2.1.7 community edition and did the composer migration. I have created a page in Magento 2 that I would like to use as my homepage. When I change the homepage to one created in Magento 2 it says "There was no Home CMS page configured or found."  I created multiple pages in Magento 2 to see if any of them could be the homepage and they could not. I have made sure all fields are filled out and the page is enabled.

Edit: Want to add I have flushed cache multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I was using single store mode so I didn't have the option to select which store view it was in. I took off single store mode, added the page to the view I use, and it works.